# Search not working in MongoDB Api in postman

Tags: mongodb, api, postman

So I was doing MERN stack and made a backend API on MongoDB Cluster and on searching specific element in it on postman it shows all element .
I was implementing search on web page and it was not able to find error so when checked on Postman and I am unable to search anything is not working.

[screen shot of postman search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOBse.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try q="holidays", i don't know exactly why it works but this is how I solved it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).